# Is it possible to construct geometrically the ($\phi$, $\Gamma$)-module corresponding to a $p$-adic representation coming from geometry?

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, hodge-theory, etale-cohomology, galois-representations

The $p$-adic étale cohomology of algebraic varieties over $p$-adic fields is a fundamental subject in the study of $p$-adic representations. Moreover, thanks to the comparison theorems in $p$-adic Hodge theory, the resulting $p$-adic representations that emerge in this way can be controlled as linear objects, such as weak admissible filtered φ-modules. It is now well-known that the corresponding filtered φ-module can be realized as cohomology, such as the crystalline cohomology of the algebraic variety X.

On the other hand, it is also well-known that one can construct étale (\phi, \Gamma)-modules from $p$-adic representations, which is also helpful in understanding $p$-adic representations. Therefore, my question is, when a $p$-adic representation comes from an algebraic variety X as described above, is it possible to "directly" construct the corresponding ($\phi$, $\Gamma$)-module from X?

Comment: When $X$ is an elliptic curve, [it](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132233/examples-of-phi-gamma-modules) can be worked out.

Comment: @Justauser Thank you for the interesting post. However, what you shared seems a bit different from what I was inquiring about. What you mentioned is the ability to compute the ($\phi$, $\Gamma$)-module of an elliptic curve, but my question was about whether there's a "something" akin to cohomology that geometrically constructs the (\phi, \Gamma)-module of an elliptic curve.